# How do I remove SELinux?

Tags: server, uninstall

How do I remove SELinux in Ubuntu Server 10.04 as the config file is not located in `/etc/selinux` and the folder `/selinux` is empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu does not use SELinux. If the directory is annoying you, remove it with:

```
sudo rmdir /selinux
```

A similar application to SELinux which is used by Ubuntu is called [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor), but this is not enabled by default.

Comment: I just failed miserably. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

**SELinux**

Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) is a Linux feature that provides a variety of security policies for Linux kernel. It is included with CentOS / RHEL / Fedora Linux,  and many other distributions.

**AppArmor**

AppArmor (Application Armor) is another security software for Linux . AppArmor was created as an alternative to SELinux. It is included with Ubuntu